# Jenkins runs as root instead of Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I have a newly installed jenkins server running on my computer, and am having some issues related to permissions.

It seems that jenkins creates the workspace directory as the root user, and then of course all task (including even pulling from the repository) fail, because they do not have permissions to modify the directory

Comment: Jenkins does not create the workspace directory as the root user.... Unless of course you're running Jenkins as root?

Comment: It seems for some reason on the first run, it created it as root and caused all these issues down the line. Deleting the workspace directory solved the issue (it recreated it with correct permissions on the next build of something)

Comment: Deleting the workspace is not an uncommon solution to this kind of problem. It suggests that some other process (custom installer?) is creating the job and not setting up the correct permisions. Are using a configuration management technology like Chef or Puppet? If so check the file ownership on files and directories.

Comment: I was not - it was my own fault in this case. Because I put the slave intialization java call, in the global start-up directory (OSX) before deciding against it, which caused it to run as sudo just once... Leading to the problems you described

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Started-By Environment Variable plugin:
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Started-By+Environment+Variable+Plugin

If you are just asking how to set up Jenkins to run under a different user in Linux it depends on how you installed it. Have a look at https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins for different setup options. I had a look at Installing Jenkins as a Unix daemon and at step 7 you need to setup a configuration file. Change the last line in that file (RUN_AS_USER=jenkins) to contain the user of your choice.